# XmlWriter in non locking mode

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I wanna to have the ability to write an XML file with XmlTextWriter or LINQ to XML but by the way I don't want the file to be locked completely. I wanna the other processes to be able to read the Xml file. It should be locked only in write mode so that the others may not modify the file.
What is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: I don't know how to achieve what you ask for... BUT I strongly recommend that you redesing your approach since most XML parsers are NOT suited for handling XML files which change while being read... with potentially severe consequences.

Comment: BTW, you don't want to use XmlTextWriter directly. If you have to use an XmlWriter, then you should use XmlWriter.Create to create one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set this when you open the FileStream.  Try this:

```
var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fs);
```

As Yahia mentions, there is no guarantee that the data written at any point will be meaningful to a reader.

Comment: I wanna that simply another application designed by me will be able to access the file with certain frequence in order to get constantly the updated file which is updated too with certain frequence.

Comment: As long as the data in the file is meaningful at the time you read it, you should be OK with this.  Make sure you call fs.Flush() after each write, or the data might not be written to disk yet.

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro: I don't think you quite understand what Chris and Yahia are saying though.  Invalid XML will not be able to be parsed, and you cannot guarantee at any time while writing that the structure will be valid.  Read locks are the simplest and least of your problems here.

Comment: Ok..But I will not write sequentially but simply add markers to a already defined Xml structure.

Comment: That doesn't really matter- you still need to ensure that the entire XML structure is written out to the file before anyone can meaningfully read it, and the normal way to do that is to block readers until you are done writing, then close your file stream.

Comment: Ok so you say that the clients should have a try catch structure and to try until the server frees the file..And what if the server writes many Kb / sec and the file will never be freed ?

Comment: Then you will never have a meaningful structure for the clients, and (to Yahia's original point) you need something like a Message Queue, not a file.

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro: That's kind of the point; you have a larger design issue to solve.  As R. Chen would say, you have the problem 90% solved, now you are trying to solve that last 10% that doesn't make any sense.  You need to revisit the design at a high level.